# How to divide a Certain Model into two parts in Razor View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, articulate

I am using Articulate plugin in Umbraco for Blog Style and I need to show something default inside every Articulate Post.
Here is what is happening now.

```
<section class="post-content">
   @Model.Body
</section>
```

And I need to do something below

```
<section class="post-content">
   @Model.Body.part1
   "Something Very Important"
   @Model.Body.part2
</section>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your can create partial views for each 'part'

Comment: It is a plugin, I don't have access to those Models. I only can do edit this View. :(

Comment: with javascript after the rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two partial views and pass the same model to both. On each view just render the part you want.

```
<section class="post-content">
   @* the model will be passed to the partial view *@
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/PartialView1.cshtml"); 

   <p>Something very important here</p>

   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/PartialView2.cshtml");
</section>
```

Then your partial views would be something like:

**PartialView1.cshtml**

```
<div>
   @Model.Body.part1
</div>
```

**PartialView2.cshtml**

```
<div>
   @Model.Body.part2
</div>
```

You don't really need the `<div>` but you get the point, right?

Comment: Glad to help. can you please mark the answer as the solution?